# Is there a way to create element inside all the div with same class names?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html. I want to create multiple div inside a sub class.

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="sub"></div>
    </div>
```

This is my script. I tried using for loop.

```
    for(let x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementsByClassName("sub")[y].appendChild(box);
};
```

Note- At first loop will target sub(div) using indexes. Then loop will create 5 div inside each sub(div).

Is there a way to target all the div with same class name and create element without using loop?

Comment: What second loop?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a loop? You want to do a similar thing multiple times; that is what loops are for!

Answer (score -1):

Loop is required.

You can target divs with `document.querySelectorAll(".main div.sub")`. You need to iterate the result and appendChild.

MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

**Example**

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".main div.sub")

nodeList.forEach((node, index) => {
  let box = document.createElement("div")
  box.innerText = index;
  node.appendChild(box);
});
```

```css
.sub > div {
  margin: 3px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

div.sub {
 border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "You need to iterate the result" — That doesn't meet the "without a loop" requirement of the quesiton

Comment: @Quentin OP intention (as per my understanding) a loop without hard coding the count `5`

Comment: That isn't what they said though.